# Entity Framework ModelBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've been struggling with this problem for quite some time now.  I just can't seem to get my entity objects to update correctly when using UpdateModel().

I just don't see this as a complex data model.  It seems like this should be a very common situation.  Perhaps there is something I need to add in the context for the fluent api to elminate this error, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Here are my models and context:

**Contact:**

```
public class Contact {
    public Contact() {
      this.ContactInformations = new HashSet<ContactInformation>();
    }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ContactInformation> ContactInformations { get; set; }
  }
```

**ContactInformation:**

```
public class ContactInformation {
    public int ContactInformationId { get; set; }
    public int ContactTypeId { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Information { get; set; }
}
```

**DatabaseContext:**

```
public class Database : DbContext {

    public Database()
      : base("Contacts") {
    }

    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContactInformation> ContactInformations { get; set; }
}
```

**Contact Controller.**

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, Contact form) {
      var contact = db.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContactId == id);
      UpdateModel(contact);
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**FORM DATA**

```
[0] "ContactId"  
[1] "Firstname"    
[2] "Lastname"   
[3] "ContactInformations[0].Index" 
[4] "ContactInformations[0].ContactInformationId" 
[5] "ContactInformations[0].ContactId"    
[6] "ContactInformations[0].Information"    
[7] "ContactInformations[0].ContactTypeId"
[8] "ContactInformations[1].Index" 
[9] "ContactInformations[1].ContactInformationId" 
[10] "ContactInformations[1].ContactId"    
[11] "ContactInformations[1].Information"    
[12] "ContactInformations[1].ContactTypeId"
```

**UPDATE**
related issue with some interesting details to my problem [Here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1650310/4290239.aspx/1?MVC%203%20Master%20Detail%20view%20inserts%20new%20detail%20records%20instead%20of%20updating%20existing%20records%20on%20controller%20UpdateModel)

Comment: My $0.02: Don't bind directly to EF entities. Use edit/view models. Not what you're asking, I know, but it will make this issue irrelevant in the end.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz I have no problems doing anything that will make this code just work.  This is such a hack its embarrassing to even post this question.  If I use a viewmodel how would you suggest synchronizing the ContactInformation in the form with the contact information of the contact being edited?  I'm open to ANY suggestions.

Comment: Well, before we go down that road, another thought occurred to me: Do you have a cascade in the DB, and did the cascade mapping get into your model? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477872/problem-with-cascade-delete-using-entity-framework-and-system-data-sqlite

Comment: @Craig Stuntz I'm not using any sort of designer.  I'm using the entity framework 4.1 code first so all my model objects are just poco classes.  I can use the fluent API, but I haven't needed to so far because of the conventions being used.

Comment: OK, but the cascade question is still relevant. Do you have a cascade in your DB and model?

Comment: @Craig Stuntz I have no cascade on delete setup on the database side.  As for the model I have nothing configured for my model explicitly.  I've included all my configurations.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz Not for sure if this will help but here is the link to an Hg repo with all the code.  http://code.google.com/p/contactsctp5/

Answer (score 0):

Relationships in EF are first-class entities. So when you break this connection you must (1) remove the relationship and (2) delete the entity. In this code:

```
  foreach (var item in needDeleted) {
    //have to use the datacontext directly.  I desperately want this gone!
    db.ContactInformations.Remove(db.ContactInformations.Single(c => c.ContactInformationId == item.ContactInformationId));

    //This will produce the same error as UpdateModel(contact)
    //contact.ContactInformations.Remove(contact.ContactInformations.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContactInformationId == item.ContactInformationId));
  }
```

... you do (1) but not (2).

You *could* do:

```
  foreach (var item in needDeleted) {
    var ci = contact.ContactInformations.Single(c => c.ContactInformationId == item.ContactInformationId);
    contact.ContactInformations.Remove(ci); // 1
    db.ContactInformations.Remove(ci);      // 2
  }
```

However, the more common way is to put a cascade on the FK and surface that in your model. In which case (1) will work by itself.

Comment: FWIW I would *still* suggest using a view model, but that would just push this issue further down the road; you will need to solve it as above.

Comment: First I truly appreciate you taking the time to look at my code.  The code I have above in my question actually works correctly, it is just IMO awful code.  I would ideally like to just say UpdateModel(contact) and MVC takes care of all the fluff of having to figure out which entities have been modified/added/deleted.  I hate that I have to access the context directly and I can't achieve the removal through the object itself.  It just seems weird that with EF you can easily do a contact.ContactInformation.Add(entity) but not a contact.ContactInformation.Remove(entity).

Comment: My comments in this answer concern the error message in your question. Updating the relationship but not deleting the object is one thing which I know can cause that issue. I suspect that's what's happening when you're doing the UpdateModel. A cascade on the model should take care of that "fluff", even with UpdateModel.

Comment: So I'm not following what your suggested solution is while still allowing me to use the UpdateModel() call?

Comment: Use POCO view models and write a function to map them onto entities.