# How can I stop "Cascade Delete" from being silently removed by Entity Framework?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-4, cascading-deletes, edmx

I have a cascade delete set in my database. I have also set a cascade delete for the corresponding relationship in my EDMX model.

However if I delete the tables with the relationship from the EDMX and then add them back in through "Update Model From Database" - the cascade has been removed.

Craig Stuntz in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477872/problem-with-cascade-delete-using-entity-framework-and-system-data-sqlite) suggests that it is a feature, however if my cascades are being silently removed each time I do an update of the model - that's unworkable.

Perhaps I need to change my workflow and not delete and re-add tables in the EDMX, rather just make all the little individual column changes by hand?

Answer (score 0):

If you delete anything from your model you also delete all your changes. Your changes are gone and EDMX doesn't know about them any more. Once you add tables again you must do all your changes again as well.

If you want to keep your changes don't delete your entities and instead run wizard directly. It should just update existing entities without removing most of your changes. I'm aware only about single example where this doesn't work and your changes are lost and that relates to renaming some navigation properties.