# How to delete contained objBs from objA on ActionResult Delete?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

Trying to remove ICollection of B's from obj A in delete action but get this error:

*"ErrorThe DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "*

Makes sense but I just don't know how to delete the contained ICollection of Bs first or thought they would automatically be removed:

```
 public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {            
        A objA = db.As.Find(id);
        //  **NOTE:**  objA has a ICollection of objB's here that I tried to iterate and
        //             delete them here using: foreach (var i in A.Bs) {db.Bs.Remove(i);} : didn't work
        db.As.Remove(objA);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database you need to edit the foreign key constraint and specify DELETE CASCADE option so that when you delete that object all its references are also deleted.

[image]

See [SQL Server Foreign Key Update and Delete Rules](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2365/sql-server-foreign-key-update-and-delete-rules/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Hasan here - just providing more info specific to Entity Framework since thats where this was tagged.

Note entity frameworks specific behavior here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx

```
    If you add an Cascade delete rule to the model, you MUST have a corresponding DELETE rule in the database.
    If you absolutely insist on breaking rule (1) for some reason, Cascade will only work if you have all the dependents loaded in memory.
    (2) is *not* recommended!!!
```

Also
[Problem with cascade delete using Entity Framework and System.Data.SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477872/problem-with-cascade-delete-using-entity-framework-and-system-data-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id) 
{             
    A objA = db.As.Find(id); 
    objA.Bs.Clear();
    db.As.Remove(objA); 
    db.SaveChanges(); 
    return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
}
```